# document.getElementById() variable onclick

Tags: javascript, html

first thank you for helping me. I think I have a simpl problem but I can't figure it out. I hava a script similar to the one below to show or hide a part of my website.

It works as it is, but I want to make 1 change,

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }    
</script>



<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
    <div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

i have another script that makes multiple tables with each a difrent button and a difrent Id name.

I want to send a variable with the onclick action like this:

```
<script>
document.write('<button onclick="myFunction('+item1+')">Click Me</button>);
</script>
```

so that evry button hides or shows another part. is there a way to make the getElementById("myDIV"); veriable?

I hope I've explaint is properly.

thank you for your time

Comment: Don't use inline javascript (such as `onclick`).  Then, assign a class (not ID) to select every item that needs a common action.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function and pass the `id` as an argument. You'll need to wrap the function call in an anonymous function.

And, really don't use `document.write()`. That is only useful when creating new `window` objects and building them up from scratch.

```
<script>
    function myFunction(buttonID) {
        var x = document.getElementById(buttonID);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }    
</script>

<button onclick="function(){ myFunction(item1) }">Click Me</button>
<div id="myDIV">This is my DIV element.</div>
```